# Java Inheritance and Wrapping

Tags: java, inheritance, code-generation, wrapper

I have a generated object that I want to:

1. Preserve existing functionality of without injecting into the constructor and rewriting every method to call `injectedObject.sameMethod()`.
2. Add additional functionality to that generated object without modifying the generated object.

add additional functionality to.

For example:

```
public class GeneratedObject {
    public String getThis() { ... }
    public String getThat() { ... }
}

public interface ObjectWrapper {
    String doThisWithThat();
}

public class ObjectWrapperImpl extends GeneratedObject implements ObjectWrapper {
    String doThisWithThat() { ... }
}
```

However, downcasting is not allowed, what is the proper implementation without rewriting a bunch of redundant code just to wrap the object?

Comment: `Add additional functionality to that generated object without modifying the generated object.` If I understand you correctly, this sounds something like `I want to add a desk into a room without touching the room.` I hope the contradiction is obvious there. Additionally, I don't fully understand the question. How does the example relate?

Comment: Composition instead of inheritance maybe?

Comment: @cklab what I am trying to say, to fit your analogy, is that `I want to add a desk outside of my room while still having access to my room`

Comment: Nope.  You totally need to override all the methods to delegate to the backing instance, in the decorator pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I think [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) may help you: "The decorator pattern can be used to extend (decorate) the functionality of a certain object at run-time, independently of other instances of the same class"

Comment: -1: seems he has no control over the `GeneratedObject`. You have to use dynamic proxying to (at least partially) implement the decorator pattern in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried aspectj?  http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-declare.html   It's a bit complicated but so is your request.

Answer (score 0):

If you can extract an interface from `GeneratedObject`, then it would be possible to do this using a [dynamic proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html). You would make a proxy which implemented the extracted interface and `ObjectWrapper`, with an invocation handler which passed all calls to methods in the `GeneratedObject` interface through to the delegate, and sent the `doThisWithThat()` calls elsewhere.

Proxies aren't pretty, but the ugliness is at least well-localised.